# LWC event listener in head markup

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, lightning-events

I'm an analyst working with a developper to receive some values from a LWC. We are trying to pass values through dispatch/listener, but the eventlistener is not triggered.

The end goal will be to some values from the LWC through to Google Tag Manager.

In the LWC we have:

```
@api Name_Label; 
@api Title_Label;
@api Call_Label;
@api Video;
@api Close;
@api Background_image;
dispatchEvent;



//Boolean tracked variable to indicate if modal is open or not default value is false as modal is closed when page is loaded 
@track isModalOpen = false;
openModal() {
    // to open modal set isModalOpen tarck value as true
    this.isModalOpen = true;

    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("updateGTMdataLayer", { "detail" : { data: "test"} }));
}
closeModal() {
    // to close modal set isModalOpen tarck value as false
    this.isModalOpen = false;
}
submitDetails() {
    // to close modal set isModalOpen tarck value as false
    //Add your code to call apex method or do some processing
    this.isModalOpen = false;
}
}
```

Then I have placed in the head markup this script to log into the console that the event triggered.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('updateGTMdataLayer', function(e){ console.log("updateGTMdataLayer")});
</script>
```

Can someone care to help?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take the quick [tour]. Your question, while not terrible, doesn't provide enough information to provide much more than a generic answer. You may want to consider making an [edit] to add more details, such as What you're trying to do specifically, as well as surrounding context. As is, I feel it might be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There may be better alternatives/solutions if you include more information.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue you're experiencing is related to LWC's shadow DOM.

> Every web component’s DOM is encapsulated in a shadow DOM that other components can’t see. When an event bubbles (bubbles = true), it doesn’t cross a shadow boundary unless you configure it to (composed = true).

Try updating the event object to:

```
{ detail: { data: "test" }, bubbles: true, composed: true }
```

I found this quote from this resource: [How Events Bubble in Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/08/how-events-bubble-in-lightning-web-components#:%7E:text=Every%20web%20component%27s%20DOM%20is,Shadow%20DOM%20enables%20component%20encapsulation.)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind if we run into any other issues. We finally got it to work after the dev used "document." instead of "this.". That might have solved the shadow Dom issue too.